# How To Remove Object from NSMutableArray After Switching Tab View

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, uitabbarcontroller

So I am trying to remove all objects in an array, `[myMutableArray removeAllObjects]`, whenever a button is pushed or the tab view changes. I know that for a button, I can use `prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender`, and it works. But how do I do the same with a tab?

I am doing this because I am using Parse, a web backend service, and I am querying for the user's friends and putting it on a tableview, but unless I remove all the objects from the array, I get duplicates of the names.

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should provide a delegate for your `UITabBarController`. This delegate should implement method `- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController`. And you place your code there. Like this:

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    [myMutableArray removeAllObjects];// if the delegate is the object holding reference to the array. otherwise put objects removal into a separate method and send this message from here 

}
```

or like that if the delegate is a different object:

```
 - (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
 {
   [myObj removeObjects];
 }

- (void)removeObjects//provide this method for a class which holds myMutableArray
  {
     [myMutableArray removeAllObjects];  
  }
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

Instead of removing them when you leave you can do it when the view reappears

```
-(void)ViewWillAppear:(BOOL)Animated
```

In some of my apps I run a check for duplicates in the

```
-(NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
```

Setting the fetchedResultsController to nil will call the function